# Undefined references when compiling opencv C++ file

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm completely new to OpenCV and I'm having trouble compiling my first program as I get undefined references to every function. I'm on `Ubuntu 14.04`. I've searched other similar problems and the solution seems to be including the `imgcodecs` library, which is already included in my program.

Here's the error I'm getting -

```
kettle@kettle-MacBookPro:~/opencvtutorials$ make
Scanning dependencies of target load_display
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/load_display.dir/load_display.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable load_display
CMakeFiles/load_display.dir/load_display.cpp.o: In function `main':
load_display.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
```

and many other similar undefined references.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt, in accordance with the tutorials.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(load_display)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(load_display load_display.cpp)
target_link_libraries(load_display ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Here's load_display.cpp -

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    ..code

    image = imread( imageName, IMREAD_COLOR ); // Read the file

    .. more code
}
```

And I'm taking the following steps to compile and run my program -

```
$ cmake .
$ make
```

Comment: This seems to be a common issue with no real fix. For a workaround, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887759/including-opencv-with-cmake-linux).

Comment: How did you install **OpenCV** and which version have you installed?

Comment: I changed the target_link_libraries line to specifically include the libraries that I'm using as mentioned in your link - `target_link_libraries(load_display opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs)` but now I get the following errors - `/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/load_display.dir/load_display.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv'
//usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: @MarkSetchell By running this [installation script](https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh) from this [website](http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/)

Comment: So you installed OpenCV 3.2.0? What happened to lines 56-61 of the script you linked to? Also, AFAIK the example code you show is for OpenCV version 2, not 3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42307835/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'd already looked at that answer, it doesn't change anything, and the error remains the same. I tried it again with my updated libraries but it still gives me the errors mentioned in my comment above. And I don't really remember what happened with lines 56-61.